# Get generated checkbox Checked State

Tags: android, checkbox, generate

I generate checkboxes with the following code:

```
public void drawCAnswers(int pst){
    rcflag = 1;
    int drawables = qmclist.get(pst).getAnswers().size();
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[drawables];
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i=0; i<drawables;i++){
        cbs[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        cbs[i].setId(i);
        cbs[i].setText(current.getAnswers().get(i).getAns());
        ll.addView(cbs[i]);
    }
    parentLinearLayout.addView(ll, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
}
```

I would like to be able, upon clicking a button, to check which of the checkboxes are selected, and get their text. How exactly could I accomplish this with my code?

Setting an onClick Listener doesn't seem right, because it's only when I click the "Next" button that I should see which ones are checked, it doesn't matter if before clicking someones (de)selects a checkbox.

For example, in the image below, it's when I click on "Question suivante" that I should get the text of the two selected checkboxes, and eventually save them in some list.

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set the onclicklistener on the next button.  Make sure the onclicklistener has access to the checkbox array.

Comment: add  checked change listener for checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try get string and store into list when facing checked change event.
Try this:

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```js
for (int i=0; i<drawables;i++){
    cbs[i] = new CheckBox(this);
    cbs[i].setId(i);
    cbs[i].setText(current.getAnswers().get(i).getAns());
    cbs[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    yourList.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    yourList.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                }
            }
    });
    ll.addView(cbs[i]);
}
```